# Laravel relationships in CRUD application

Tags: mysql, laravel

I want to create a CRUD application with Laravel with the following scenario:
 we have a mine in which various trucks take mining material from a mining hole and though a road they deposit it in a dump hole. Now each road connects an area with a dump hole.  So "Road No1" takes material and from "Area 1" and disposes into "dump hole 1". Road No2 takes material from "Area 1" as well and might dispose it to "dump hole 1" too. So areas and roads have one-to-many relationship like one area can have many roads and dump holes with roads should have a one-to-many relationship as well, like one dump hole gets material from many roads.

Taking for granted that areas, roads and dump holes are three different tables, is it completely necessary to create a relationship between these three tables as mentioned above ? And if yes I was wondering if this will create duplicate values in the roads table in case the user want to see the dumps site that a road put material to or an area the roads come from. For example consider the following table:

```
+----+-------------+----------+-------+---------+---------------+
| id | route       | distance | slope | area    | dumpsite      |
+----+-------------+----------+-------+---------+---------------+
|  2 | First route |    10000 |    20 | E12     | Big Dumpsite  |
|  3 | Second route|     2000 |    15 | E12     | Huge Dumpsite |
|  4 | Third route |     2555 |    10 | E13     | Big Dumpsite  |
+----+-------------+----------+-------+---------+---------------+
```

as you can see in area and dumpsite columns there duplicate values.

Is this good design ?

Comment: The example you posted is the road table, right? Anyway if I understood correctly your needs, I would have a table for areas, one for dumpholes and a road pivot table that takes in the PK of areas and dumpholes plus whichever other attributes specific to the road.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can understand, you would setup your models like this

```
class Area extends Model
{
    public function roads() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Road');
    }

    // to access areas possible dumpsites
    public function getDumpsitesAttribute()
    {
        return $this->roads->with('dumpsite')->get()->pluck('dumpsite')->unique();
    }
}

class Road extends Model
{
    public function area() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Area');
    }

    public function dumpsite() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Dumpsite');
    }
}

class Dumpsite extends Model
{
    public function roads() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Road');
    }

    // to access dumpsites possible area
    public function getAreasAttribute()
    {
        return $this->roads->with('area')->get()->pluck('area')->unique();
    }
}
```

And your `road` table would have `area_id` and `dumpsite_id`

Comment: ah thank you! This probably will do! A couple more questions: is it really necessary to relate tables? And also do I need to add constraints like onUpdate() and onDelete() ? What about the duplicate values that will appear on the table?